# Does disabling "System Integrity Protection" in El Cap cause shutdown/restart/logout issues?

Tags: macos, sip

I have an older M-Audio Firewire audio interface that I use with my Mid 2011 Mac Mini. It's running OS X El Capitan 10.11.6. M-Audio never made drivers for this version of OS X, so I have to disable "System Integrity Protection" for the audio interface to work. I do this by booting to recovery > Terminal: `csrutil disable` then rebooting normally.

However, I have an issue where I cannot logout, restart or shutdown "cleanly." What I typically do is run the `sudo restart now` command to reboot, or `sudo pkill loginwindow` to log out. EDIT: What I mean here is **OS X (El Cap) is getting "stuck" (just hanging indefinitely) when I try to either a.)logout b.)restart or c.)shutdown. It just does not work, so I use terminal commands to force it, but I want to stop having to do this.**

Could this issue be related to disabling SIP? EDIT: I have disabled SIP, no change. They are not related.

Comment: It shouldn't be, but it might. Try reenabling SIP. If it fixes the problem, you've found it, if not try looking for other causes.

Comment: Disabling SIP did not help my issue. Any ideas on what else to try?

Comment: My only other thought would be to reinstall the OS and then try again

Comment: Oh man, that's too much! Surely there's something else I try...

Comment: Ok, so removed my answer for not being an actual answer. My first question: do you _always_ experience the described problems? Or just sometimes? When macOS `hangs` it is usually because one or more specific processes are at fault. Could you check the output of `ps aux` in terminal if there might be any processes take a large amount of CPU or MEM usage?

Comment: Thank you. Yes, always. I will try the `ps aux` command...

Comment: You could also try holding down the command-key when shutting down or logging out.This will skip the pop-up confirmation window you usually would get. So holding down the command-key would help prevent the very rare case in which this window might be what is actually at fault.

Comment: Finally, as a first try.. try to search the `ps aux` output for any M-audio related processes (you could use `ps aux | grep -i whatyouarelookingfor` to ease your search). Kill these processes and execute a regular reboot. Did that help? It might be macOS gets stuck on trying to close these processes if they aren't actually compatible anymore..

Comment: What should I be looking for? I tried this   `bash-3.2# ps aux | grep -i M-Audio
root                76   0.0  0.0   659960   3764   ??  Ss   10:45PM   0:00.29 /Library/StartupItems/M-Audio FireWire Audio Helper/M-Audio FireWire Device Helper start
root              1135   0.0  0.0  2452248    804 s000  S+    8:47AM   0:00.01 grep -i M-Audio`

Comment: ...but it doesn't really tell me anything..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a software issue, after all. Once I upgraded to macOS High Sierra I was once again able to reboot normally, regardless of SIP status.